# bash: file: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash

I have ubuntu docker container. I installed there some applicaiton compiled in windows for ubuntu.

It does not execute and I'd like to check if there is a mismatch between the system architecture and the file. I try this command

```
> file myapp
```

but unfortunately output is

```
> bash: file: command not found
```

Really, in bin directory there is no "file" command. Is it somewhere else or I need I install it?

[image]

Comment: Do a `which file` and if no result then its not there install it.. remember your using a `docker container` it might not have all you need!

Comment: Did you install the package `coreutils` in your container? Try `sudo apt-get install coreutils` and see the result.

Comment: @KoalaYeung it's not in `core-utils`, the package is `file`

Comment: @Zanna when a program is core-utils its result would be `/sbin/file` right?

Comment: @George looks to me like the `core-utils` stuff is in `/bin`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Docker images typically do not contain more than the bare essentials, and it seemed whoever created this container didn't deem `file` necessary. You'll have to install it, the package is also called `file`.

Comment: Don't forget to `apt-get update` before `apt-get install file`